# How to flip wordpress wp mega menu sub menu from below to above

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, wp-mega-menu

[image]

I have this menu here in wp mega menu wordpress plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-megamenu/

Ive been fighting through the whole day trying to figure the css to give me the desired end result in the picture. Can anyone point me in the direction of the correct css selector(s) to edit in order to achieve the menu coming from the bottom going up, instead of the default dropdown behavior where the menu goes from the top to the bottom?

Comment: Its pretty simple. Please past your HTML code, so i can give you some hints to do this using css

Comment: in my html there isn't anything really. All there is a shortcode. As for the css, its all dynamic generated through the plugin, but when i try to use web developer mode in the browser i cannot find the selector to edit. so i don't know exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Switching the sub menu styling from `top: 100%` to `bottom: 100%` would probably be a good start

Comment: sounds easy enough. My problem however is in locating the appropriate selector to change it. Ive played with a ton of selectors so far and none are working out

Comment: i finally figured it out. it was ul .wp-megamenu-sub-menu

Comment: Please share your website URL or HTML that is generated after using shortcode or Plugin function.